# Changing tableView content inset while ending refresh?

Tags: swift, tableview

I found out that changing the tableView's `contentInset` while `endingRefreshing()` conflicts each other.

**Code:**

```
func reloadData(){

    ...

    self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
    self.displayInfoViewIfNeeded()
}



func displayInfoViewIfNeeded(){
    if self.shouldInfoViewBeVisible == true {

        self.infoView.isHidden = false

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25){
           self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 50, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        }

    } else {

        self.infoView.isHidden = true

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25){
            self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        }

    }

}
```

The problem is that sometimes it causes weird inset outcomes.

How could I fix that? I need a little space at the top if `shouldInfoViewBeVisible == true` (because then I display a view above the tableView on the top).

Is there another way to achieve this? Or what would you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x:0,y:50)
```

Another attempt to hook top constraint of the table as outlet , then do

```
self.tblTop.constant = shouldInfoViewBeVisible ? 0 : 50
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25){
   self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I need to have the view on top on the tableView (so that under the infoView bubble the tableView is visible): therefore the constraint method doesn’t solve my problem. Neither does the offset changing: it is not permament. :/